# In Magento 2.3, How to add custom error code with response

Tags: magento2, api, json-response

In Magento 2.3, How to add custom error code along with response.
For example,
If I add the code as below, I am getting this below response:

> throw new InvalidEmailOrPasswordException(__('Invalid login or
>   password.'), null, 900)

```
"message": "Invalid login or password.",
    "code": 900,
    "trace": "#0 [internal function]
```

But this is only accepting integer(900), not any characters. Is any poosibility to add this characters in the code.
Thanks in Advance.